# Creating nginx configuration files with script and variable expansion

Tags: bash, shell-script, here-document

I'm trying to create a nginx configuration file using a `here-document` with variable expansion. I use:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
settings
EOF
```

It works and expands the variables I need, but there are variables that need to be printed literally, so it's breaking my configuration file.

Example of lines I need to print literally:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:30m rate=20r/s;
try_files $uri =404;
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the `$` with a `\` of those variables you don't want to replace:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
limit_req_zone \$binary_remote_addr zone=one:30m rate=20r/s;
try_files \$uri =404;
EOF
```

Comment: While this works I have a ugly workaround...just print everything literally then sed the stuff later :O that's easier than escaping everything needed

Comment: Or use `envsubst` to replace only specific variables like `export var1=foo var2=bar; envsubst '$var1 $var2' < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.new`